# UITouch force property relation?

Tags: uikit, uitouch, 3dtouch

The new `force` property on `UITouch` is great, but I would like to get some values I can put it in relation to. For example the value the OS uses to start a peek and the value it uses for a pop. Of course I could make my own ones up, but the ones iOS uses internally depend on accessiblity settings as well and therefore differ from device to device. Has anyone got any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Why do you need the exact values? Are you recreating your own peek implemenetation or just curious

Comment: @SnoApps Exactly that. I actually got an implementation working with just made up values that felt right, but the underlying issue still remains. This API is not really meant for anyone to implement their own peeks, it's probably just there for some small games.

Comment: Or if you wanted a peek that's way more customizable than what the built in api allows. But ya games are a more likely use for this api in the future

Comment: @SnoApps I doubt that, since you can't even get access to the haptic engine, so even though you can theoretically create better peeks, they aren't actually better. Trust me, I tried.